# Is it possible to pass variables between stylesheets?

Tags: html, css

Or is it even possible to use variables to a single stylesheet without the use of preprocessors?

Comment: Sorry, the answer currently is (still) No.

Answer (score 1):

CSS at present does not support variables. Mozilla does have a proposal, but it is not widely implemented.

Comment: Thats too bad. But is it possible to use php?

Comment: @Pa3k.m you could generate a stylesheet using php and its variables.